# How do I put multiple JPanels (3) in a JPanel Using JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am trying to create a gui app using JTabbedPane to create 5 tabs connected to a database. Each tab contains a panel with 3 panels in it (one panel to hold JButtons another to hold JLabels and JTextFields and the last to hold a JTable. Each to the South, Center and North respectively). But after creating the tabs and its components, only the last tab displays and it displays incorrectly (it displays the JLabels, JTextfields and JButtons of all 5 tabs). If I remove all tabs and leave one it displays correctly but if more than one, it displays on the last tab. I don't know how to resolve it. Please help me.

The source code is a bit lengthy so please bear with me and help me check it. If there is a better way to write the code please let me know.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Project_SalesDatabase extends JFrame {

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
JButton view = new JButton(" View ");
JButton save = new JButton(" Save ");
JButton addNew = new JButton(" Add New ");
JButton exit = new JButton(" Exit Application ");
JPanel displayBiscuitsPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel displayCookingPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel displayCustomersPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel displayEmployeesPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel displayProvisionsPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel displayButton = new JPanel();
JPanel displayContent = new JPanel((new GridLayout(10, 2)));
JPanel displayTable = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
JTextField biscuitName = new JTextField();
JTextField biscuitPrice = new JTextField();
JTextField biscuitCompany = new JTextField();
JTextField quantityOfBiscuitsBought = new JTextField();
JTextField quantityOfBiscuitsSold = new JTextField();
JTextField quantityInStock = new JTextField();
JTextField itemName = new JTextField();
JTextField itemPrice = new JTextField();
JTextField itemType = new JTextField();
JTextField quantityOfitemsBought = new JTextField();
JTextField quantityOfitemsSold = new JTextField();
JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
JTextField customerAttendant = new JTextField();
JTextField customerAttendantPosition = new JTextField();
JTextField isCustomerADebtor = new JTextField();
JTextField orderNumber = new JTextField();
JTextField debtAmount = new JTextField();
JTextField address = new JTextField();
JTextField phoneNumber = new JTextField();
JTextField position = new JTextField();
JTextField age = new JTextField();
JTextField salary = new JTextField();
JTextField nextOfKin = new JTextField();
JTextField relationshipWithNextOfKin = new JTextField();
JTextField nextOfKinPhoneNumber = new JTextField();
JTextField itemCompany = new JTextField();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Project_SalesDatabase mainFrame = new Project_SalesDatabase();
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public Project_SalesDatabase() {

    setTitle(" Database App ");
    setSize(1000, 500);

    // Create the tab pages
    biscuitsTable();
    cookingIngredientsTable();
    customersTable();
    employeesTable();
    provisionsTable();

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    getContentPane().add(topPanel);
    topPanel.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    // Create tabs in tabbedPane
    tabbedPane.addTab("Biscuits Database", icon, displayBiscuitsPanel,
            "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Biscuits Database");

    tabbedPane.addTab("Cooking Ingredients Database", icon, displayCookingPanel,
            "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Cooking Ingredients Database");

    tabbedPane.addTab("Customers Database", icon, displayCustomersPanel,
            "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Customers Database");

    tabbedPane.addTab("Employees Database", icon, displayEmployeesPanel,
            "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Employees Database");

    tabbedPane.addTab("Provisions Database", icon, displayProvisionsPanel,
            "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Provisions Database");

    //Enable scrolling in tabs.
    tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
}

public static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = Project_SalesDatabase.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

public final void biscuitsTable() {
    displayBiscuitsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    displayBiscuitsPanel.add(displayContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    displayBiscuitsPanel.add(displayButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    displayBiscuitsPanel.add(displayTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Name"));
    displayContent.add(biscuitName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Price"));
    displayContent.add(biscuitPrice);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Company"));
    displayContent.add(biscuitCompany);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Bought"));
    displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsBought);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Sold"));
    displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsSold);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
    displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

    displayButton.add(addNew);
    displayButton.add(save);
    displayButton.add(view);
    displayButton.add(exit);

    view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
            String username = "";
            String password = "";
            Connection con = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
            }

            Statement state = null;
            ResultSet set = null;

            try {

                String Query = "SELECT * FROM Biscuits";
                state = con.createStatement();
                set = state.executeQuery(Query);

                boolean nextrec = set.next();
                if (!nextrec) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Record");
                } else {
                    Vector col = new Vector();
                    Vector row = new Vector();

                    ResultSetMetaData rsm = set.getMetaData();

                    for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                        col.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(x));
                    }
                    do {
                        row.addElement(getNextRow(set, rsm));
                    } while (set.next());

                    JTable tab = new JTable(row, col);
                    displayContent.removeAll();
                    displayTable.removeAll();
                    displayTable.add(new JScrollPane(tab), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    validate();
                }
                state.close();
            } catch (SQLException sql) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, sql.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                String Query = "INSERT INTO Biscuits VALUES ('" + biscuitName.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + biscuitPrice.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + biscuitCompany.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityOfBiscuitsBought.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityOfBiscuitsSold.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityInStock.getText() + "')";

                String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                }
                Statement state = con.createStatement();
                int rep = state.executeUpdate(Query);
                if (rep == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Data Saved");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Saved");
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

    addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                biscuitName.setText("");
                biscuitPrice.setText("");
                biscuitCompany.setText("");
                quantityOfBiscuitsBought.setText("");
                quantityOfBiscuitsSold.setText("");
                quantityInStock.setText("");

                displayTable.removeAll();
                displayContent.removeAll();

                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Name"));
                displayContent.add(biscuitName);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Price"));
                displayContent.add(biscuitPrice);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Company"));
                displayContent.add(biscuitCompany);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Bought"));
                displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsBought);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Sold"));
                displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsSold);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
                displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

                validate();

            } catch (Exception f) {
                f.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public final void cookingIngredientsTable() {
    displayCookingPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    displayCookingPanel.add(displayContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    displayCookingPanel.add(displayButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    displayCookingPanel.add(displayTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
    displayContent.add(itemName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
    displayContent.add(itemPrice);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Type"));
    displayContent.add(itemType);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
    displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

    displayButton.add(addNew);
    displayButton.add(save);
    displayButton.add(view);
    displayButton.add(exit);

    view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
            String username = "";
            String password = "";
            Connection con = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
            }

            Statement state = null;
            ResultSet set = null;

            try {

                String Query = "SELECT * FROM CookingIngredients";
                state = con.createStatement();
                set = state.executeQuery(Query);

                boolean nextrec = set.next();
                if (!nextrec) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Record");
                } else {
                    Vector col = new Vector();
                    Vector row = new Vector();

                    ResultSetMetaData rsm = set.getMetaData();

                    for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                        col.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(x));
                    }
                    do {
                        row.addElement(getNextRow(set, rsm));
                    } while (set.next());
                    JTable tab = new JTable(row, col);
                    displayContent.removeAll();
                    displayTable.removeAll();
                    displayTable.add(new JScrollPane(tab), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    validate();
                }
                state.close();

            } catch (SQLException sql) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, sql.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                String Query = "INSERT INTO CookingIngredients VALUES ('" + itemName.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + itemPrice.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + itemType.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityOfitemsBought.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityOfitemsSold.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityInStock.getText() + "')";

                String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                }
                Statement state = con.createStatement();
                int rep = state.executeUpdate(Query);
                if (rep == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Data Saved");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Saved");
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

    addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                itemName.setText("");
                itemPrice.setText("");
                itemType.setText("");
                quantityOfitemsBought.setText("");
                quantityOfBiscuitsSold.setText("");
                quantityOfitemsSold.setText("");
                quantityInStock.setText("");

                displayTable.removeAll();
                displayContent.removeAll();

                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
                displayContent.add(itemName);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
                displayContent.add(itemPrice);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Type"));
                displayContent.add(itemType);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
                displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
                displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
                displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

                validate();

            } catch (Exception f) {
                f.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });
}

public final void customersTable() {
    displayCustomersPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    displayCustomersPanel.add(displayContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    displayCustomersPanel.add(displayButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    displayCustomersPanel.add(displayTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    displayContent.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
    displayContent.add(firstName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
    displayContent.add(lastName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Customer Attendant"));
    displayContent.add(customerAttendant);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Customer Attendant's Position"));
    displayContent.add(customerAttendantPosition);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Is This Customer A Debtor?"));
    displayContent.add(isCustomerADebtor);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Order Number"));
    displayContent.add(orderNumber);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Debt Amount"));
    displayContent.add(debtAmount);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Customer's Address"));
    displayContent.add(address);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Customer's Phone Number"));
    displayContent.add(phoneNumber);

    displayButton.add(addNew);
    displayButton.add(save);
    displayButton.add(view);
    displayButton.add(exit);

    //button actions same as other methods. Removed it because of body character limits
}

public final void employeesTable() {
    displayEmployeesPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    displayEmployeesPanel.add(displayContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    displayEmployeesPanel.add(displayButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    displayEmployeesPanel.add(displayTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    displayContent.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
    displayContent.add(firstName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
    displayContent.add(lastName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Position"));
    displayContent.add(position);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Age"));
    displayContent.add(age);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Salary"));
    displayContent.add(salary);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Employees's Address"));
    displayContent.add(address);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Employees's Phone Number(s)"));
    displayContent.add(phoneNumber);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Next of Kin"));
    displayContent.add(nextOfKin);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Relationship With Next of Kin"));
    displayContent.add(relationshipWithNextOfKin);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Next of Kin's Phone Number(s)"));
    displayContent.add(nextOfKinPhoneNumber);

    displayButton.add(addNew);
    displayButton.add(save);
    displayButton.add(view);
    displayButton.add(exit);

    //button actions same as other methods. Removed it because of body character limits
}

public final void provisionsTable() {
    displayProvisionsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    displayProvisionsPanel.add(displayContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    displayProvisionsPanel.add(displayButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    displayProvisionsPanel.add(displayTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
    displayContent.add(itemName);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
    displayContent.add(itemPrice);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Company"));
    displayContent.add(itemCompany);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
    displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

    displayButton.add(addNew);
    displayButton.add(save);
    displayButton.add(view);
    displayButton.add(exit);

    view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
            String username = "";
            String password = "";
            Connection con = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
            }

            Statement state = null;
            ResultSet set = null;

            try {

                String Query = "SELECT * FROM Provisions";
                state = con.createStatement();
                set = state.executeQuery(Query);

                boolean nextrec = set.next();
                if (!nextrec) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Record");
                } else {
                    Vector col = new Vector();
                    Vector row = new Vector();

                    ResultSetMetaData rsm = set.getMetaData();

                    for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                        col.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(x));
                    }
                    do {
                        row.addElement(getNextRow(set, rsm));
                    } while (set.next());

                    JTable tab = new JTable(row, col);
                    displayContent.removeAll();
                    displayTable.removeAll();
                    displayTable.add(new JScrollPane(tab), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    validate();
                }
                state.close();
            } catch (SQLException sql) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, sql.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                String Query = "INSERT INTO Provisions VALUES ('" + itemName.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + itemPrice.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + itemCompany.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityOfitemsBought.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityOfitemsSold.getText() + "',"
                        + "          '" + quantityInStock.getText() + "')";

                String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                }
                Statement state = con.createStatement();
                int rep = state.executeUpdate(Query);
                if (rep == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Data Saved");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Saved");
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

    addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                itemName.setText("");
                itemPrice.setText("");
                itemCompany.setText("");
                quantityOfitemsBought.setText("");
                quantityOfitemsSold.setText("");
                quantityInStock.setText("");

                displayTable.removeAll();
                displayContent.removeAll();

                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
                displayContent.add(itemName);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
                displayContent.add(itemPrice);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Company"));
                displayContent.add(itemCompany);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
                displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
                displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
                displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
                displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

                validate();

            } catch (Exception f) {
                f.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });
}

Vector getNextRow(ResultSet set, ResultSetMetaData rsm) {
    Vector currentRow = new Vector();
    try {
        for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
            switch (rsm.getColumnType(x)) {
                case Types.VARCHAR:
                    currentRow.addElement(set.getString(x));
                    break;
                case Types.INTEGER:
                    currentRow.addElement(new Long(set.getLong(x)));
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("No column type known");
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.getMessage();
    }
    return currentRow;
}
}
```

I don't know why its not working correctly. Please if anybody can try and compile/run it to see what I'm saying. Thanks.

Comment: OMG, so many Jtextfields and panels... did you think to put'm in list?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Please have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I am trying to create a gui app using JTabbedPane to create 5 tabs. Each tab contains a panel with 3 panels in it`

As is the nature of Swing components, you can embed one `JComponent` inside another except for `JFrame`.
So, what you need to do is to create a `JPanel`. Make sure it has a `GridLayout` for 3 cols and 1 row (or the other way around, if that is your need).
Then, add the three `JPanels` to this base JPanel which has grid layout.

Finally, add the base `JPanel` to your `JTabbedPane`. Have a look at the `JPanel` tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: I changed the panel to GridLayout but it still has the same problem. I've edited the code to include all other methods so you can compile and run (if you wish) to see what I'm trying to do. Would really appreciate.

Comment: @JimNoah Always use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to start a Swing project. You cannot start a JFrame on the main thread :)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you expect and what you get ? :)

Comment: I wanted to post the screenshots but don't have enough rep yet (says I need at least 10) and I can't find any message/pm button here. I've tried all possible methods I know and even used the method on JPanel tutorial but still not solved. All the components of the five tabs are showing on the last tab instead of each tab having its own separate components.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshots to 4shared. Please try and take a look at them. The 5 tabs are supposed to display like this: http://www.4shared.com/photo/2imqJ6TT/bis1.html http://www.4shared.com/photo/djhXtjMz/cook1.html http://www.4shared.com/photo/DfwQbDev/cus1.html http://www.4shared.com/photo/7rzz0nWH/emp1.html
http://www.4shared.com/photo/ROcHjich/prov1.html but instead it is displaying this http://www.4shared.com/photo/9aV3qZ34/jtab1.html

Comment: Still not working as intended (Still having the same issues. Displays correctly if it's one tab but incorrectly if more than one tab).Please did you try to compile and run it with your suggestions?...I've browsed through similar questions and most people suggested using the getTabComponents() and getComponent() methods but I've tried them and keep getting indexOutOfBoundsException(Says tab count is 1 whereas it's supposed to be 5).Don't understand ...just confused about java's gui(I'm new to programming and started with java)!

Comment: I hope you arent trying to add the **same components** to different tabs ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure. The components of the five tabs are identical (same components(JTextFields, JLabels & JButtons) at same positions) but with different variable names. That is different JPanels holding them in the different tabs.  I've pasted the full source code at http://pastebin.com/L8mu0jvH I would be very very grateful if you can compile and run it to better understand me. Thanks so far.

Comment: thank you I was using the same components instead of having new ones. Now working fine. I'm beginning to understand Java GUI; I could use the same components for different JFrames but now I know it doesn't work like that in JTabbedPane. Thanks to you all for your answers and ideas. Love stackoverflow - overflowing with great programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the getTabComponentAt(index) method to add components to the specific tab