# JTabbedPane...How do I make each tab show its content when clicked on?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

Please I've asked this question before but didn't get a working solution so please help me take a look and suggest solutions. Here is the link [How do I put multiple JPanels (3) in a JPanel Using JTabbedPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220469/how-do-i-put-multiple-jpanels-3-in-a-jpanel-using-jtabbedpane) Please scroll down to the comments on the last answer to visit the links and view the screenshots. You can also see the full source code at http://pastebin.com/L8mu0jvH its a bit lenghty though.

Comment: Each panel you build is reusing the same `displayPanel`, `displayTable`, and `displayButton` objects, when they really should be using separate panels. [This](http://pastebin.com/eVbdPD8V) might be what you're going for? You might also start with something easier in order to get a better understanding of [how to use a JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

Comment: First of all, create Interface of your program and then work on it.

Comment: Jim, @sbat 's advise is exactly what I told you. You are reusing the components when you should be having new ones.

Comment: _its a bit lenghty though_ then strip it down to a SSCCE (and note: code outside of SO is non-existent :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing is working good, but you need to create different display content, display panel, display table for your every tab. Check out this program, If you have any problem, feel free to ask me...!!

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class Project_SalesDatabase extends JFrame {

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
    JButton view = new JButton(" View ");
    JButton save = new JButton(" Save ");
    JButton addNew = new JButton(" Add New ");
    JButton exit = new JButton(" Exit Application ");

    JPanel displayBiscuitsPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayCookingPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayCustomersPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayEmployeesPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayProvisionsPanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel displayButton = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayButton1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayButton2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayButton3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel displayButton4 = new JPanel();

    JPanel displayContent = new JPanel((new GridLayout(10, 2)));
    JPanel displayContent1 = new JPanel((new GridLayout(10, 2)));
    JPanel displayContent2 = new JPanel((new GridLayout(10, 2)));
    JPanel displayContent3 = new JPanel((new GridLayout(10, 2)));
    JPanel displayContent4 = new JPanel((new GridLayout(10, 2)));


    JPanel displayTable = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel displayTable1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel displayTable2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel displayTable3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel displayTable4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));


    JTextField biscuitName = new JTextField();
    JTextField biscuitPrice = new JTextField();
    JTextField biscuitCompany = new JTextField();
    JTextField quantityOfBiscuitsBought = new JTextField();
    JTextField quantityOfBiscuitsSold = new JTextField();
    JTextField quantityInStock = new JTextField();
    JTextField itemName = new JTextField();
    JTextField itemPrice = new JTextField();
    JTextField itemType = new JTextField();
    JTextField quantityOfitemsBought = new JTextField();
    JTextField quantityOfitemsSold = new JTextField();
    JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
    JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
    JTextField customerAttendant = new JTextField();
    JTextField customerAttendantPosition = new JTextField();
    JTextField isCustomerADebtor = new JTextField();
    JTextField orderNumber = new JTextField();
    JTextField debtAmount = new JTextField();
    JTextField address = new JTextField();
    JTextField phoneNumber = new JTextField();
    JTextField position = new JTextField();
    JTextField age = new JTextField();
    JTextField salary = new JTextField();
    JTextField nextOfKin = new JTextField();
    JTextField relationshipWithNextOfKin = new JTextField();
    JTextField nextOfKinPhoneNumber = new JTextField();
    JTextField itemCompany = new JTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project_SalesDatabase mainFrame = new Project_SalesDatabase();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Project_SalesDatabase() {

        setTitle(" Database App ");
        setSize(1000, 500);

        // Create the tab pages
        biscuitsTable();
        cookingIngredientsTable();
        customersTable();
        employeesTable();
        provisionsTable();

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);
        topPanel.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        // Create tabs in tabbedPane
        tabbedPane.addTab("Biscuits Database", icon, displayBiscuitsPanel,
                "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Biscuits Database");

        tabbedPane.addTab("Cooking Ingredients Database", icon, displayCookingPanel,
                "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Cooking Ingredients Database");

        tabbedPane.addTab("Customers Database", icon, displayCustomersPanel,
                "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Customers Database");

        tabbedPane.addTab("Employees Database", icon, displayEmployeesPanel,
                "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Employees Database");

        tabbedPane.addTab("Provisions Database", icon, displayProvisionsPanel,
                "Allows you to view or Enter Data into the Provisions Database");

        //Enable scrolling in tabs.
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

    public static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = Project_SalesDatabase.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public final void biscuitsTable() {
        displayBiscuitsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        displayBiscuitsPanel.add(displayContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        displayBiscuitsPanel.add(displayButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        displayBiscuitsPanel.add(displayTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Name"));
        displayContent.add(biscuitName);
        displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Price"));
        displayContent.add(biscuitPrice);
        displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Company"));
        displayContent.add(biscuitCompany);
        displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Bought"));
        displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsBought);
        displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Sold"));
        displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsSold);
        displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
        displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

        displayButton.add(addNew);
        displayButton.add(save);
        displayButton.add(view);
        displayButton.add(exit);

        view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con = null;

                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                }

                Statement state = null;
                ResultSet set = null;

                try {

                    String Query = "SELECT * FROM Biscuits";
                    state = con.createStatement();
                    set = state.executeQuery(Query);

                    boolean nextrec = set.next();
                    if (!nextrec) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Record");
                    } else {
                        Vector col = new Vector();
                        Vector row = new Vector();

                        ResultSetMetaData rsm = set.getMetaData();

                        for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                            col.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(x));
                        }
                        do {
                            row.addElement(getNextRow(set, rsm));
                        } while (set.next());

                        JTable tab = new JTable(row, col);
                        displayContent.removeAll();
                        displayTable.removeAll();
                        displayTable.add(new JScrollPane(tab), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                        validate();
                    }
                    state.close();
                } catch (SQLException sql) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, sql.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    String Query = "INSERT INTO Biscuits VALUES ('" + biscuitName.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + biscuitPrice.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + biscuitCompany.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityOfBiscuitsBought.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityOfBiscuitsSold.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityInStock.getText() + "')";

                    String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                    String username = "";
                    String password = "";
                    Connection con = null;
                    try {
                        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                    }
                    Statement state = con.createStatement();
                    int rep = state.executeUpdate(Query);
                    if (rep == 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Data Saved");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Saved");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    sqle.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });

        addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {

                    biscuitName.setText("");
                    biscuitPrice.setText("");
                    biscuitCompany.setText("");
                    quantityOfBiscuitsBought.setText("");
                    quantityOfBiscuitsSold.setText("");
                    quantityInStock.setText("");

                    displayTable.removeAll();
                    displayContent.removeAll();

                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Name"));
                    displayContent.add(biscuitName);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Price"));
                    displayContent.add(biscuitPrice);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Biscuit Company"));
                    displayContent.add(biscuitCompany);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Bought"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsBought);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Biscuits Sold"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityOfBiscuitsSold);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

                    validate();

                } catch (Exception f) {
                    f.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public final void cookingIngredientsTable() {
        displayCookingPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        displayCookingPanel.add(displayContent1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        displayCookingPanel.add(displayButton1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        displayCookingPanel.add(displayTable1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        displayContent1.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
        displayContent1.add(itemName);
        displayContent1.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
        displayContent1.add(itemPrice);
        displayContent1.add(new JLabel("Item Type"));
        displayContent1.add(itemType);
        displayContent1.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
        displayContent1.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
        displayContent1.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
        displayContent1.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
        displayContent1.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
        displayContent1.add(quantityInStock);

        displayButton1.add(addNew);
        displayButton1.add(save);
        displayButton1.add(view);
        displayButton1.add(exit);

        view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                }

                Statement state = null;
                ResultSet set = null;

                try {

                    String Query = "SELECT * FROM CookingIngredients";
                    state = con.createStatement();
                    set = state.executeQuery(Query);

                    boolean nextrec = set.next();
                    if (!nextrec) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Record");
                    } else {
                        Vector col = new Vector();
                        Vector row = new Vector();

                        ResultSetMetaData rsm = set.getMetaData();

                        for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                            col.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(x));
                        }
                        do {
                            row.addElement(getNextRow(set, rsm));
                        } while (set.next());
                        JTable tab = new JTable(row, col);
                        displayContent.removeAll();
                        displayTable.removeAll();
                        displayTable.add(new JScrollPane(tab), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        validate();
                    }
                    state.close();

                } catch (SQLException sql) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, sql.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    String Query = "INSERT INTO CookingIngredients VALUES ('" + itemName.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + itemPrice.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + itemType.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityOfitemsBought.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityOfitemsSold.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityInStock.getText() + "')";

                    String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                    String username = "";
                    String password = "";
                    Connection con = null;
                    try {
                        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                    }
                    Statement state = con.createStatement();
                    int rep = state.executeUpdate(Query);
                    if (rep == 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Data Saved");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Saved");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    sqle.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });

        addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {

                    itemName.setText("");
                    itemPrice.setText("");
                    itemType.setText("");
                    quantityOfitemsBought.setText("");
                    quantityOfBiscuitsSold.setText("");
                    quantityOfitemsSold.setText("");
                    quantityInStock.setText("");

                    displayTable.removeAll();
                    displayContent.removeAll();

                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
                    displayContent.add(itemName);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
                    displayContent.add(itemPrice);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Type"));
                    displayContent.add(itemType);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

                    validate();

                } catch (Exception f) {
                    f.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public final void customersTable() {
        displayCustomersPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        displayCustomersPanel.add(displayContent2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        displayCustomersPanel.add(displayButton2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        displayCustomersPanel.add(displayTable2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        displayContent2.add(firstName);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        displayContent2.add(lastName);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Customer Attendant"));
        displayContent2.add(customerAttendant);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Customer Attendant's Position"));
        displayContent2.add(customerAttendantPosition);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Is This Customer A Debtor?"));
        displayContent2.add(isCustomerADebtor);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Order Number"));
        displayContent2.add(orderNumber);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Debt Amount"));
        displayContent2.add(debtAmount);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Customer's Address"));
        displayContent2.add(address);
        displayContent2.add(new JLabel("Customer's Phone Number"));
        displayContent2.add(phoneNumber);

        displayButton2.add(addNew);
        displayButton2.add(save);
        displayButton2.add(view);
        displayButton2.add(exit);

        //button actions same as other methods. Removed it because of body character limits
    }

    public final void employeesTable() {
        displayEmployeesPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        displayEmployeesPanel.add(displayContent3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        displayEmployeesPanel.add(displayButton3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        displayEmployeesPanel.add(displayTable3, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        displayContent3.add(firstName);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        displayContent3.add(lastName);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Position"));
        displayContent3.add(position);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Age"));
        displayContent3.add(age);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Salary"));
        displayContent3.add(salary);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Employees's Address"));
        displayContent3.add(address);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Employees's Phone Number(s)"));
        displayContent3.add(phoneNumber);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Next of Kin"));
        displayContent3.add(nextOfKin);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Relationship With Next of Kin"));
        displayContent3.add(relationshipWithNextOfKin);
        displayContent3.add(new JLabel("Next of Kin's Phone Number(s)"));
        displayContent3.add(nextOfKinPhoneNumber);

        displayButton3.add(addNew);
        displayButton3.add(save);
        displayButton3.add(view);
        displayButton3.add(exit);

        //button actions same as other methods. Removed it because of body character limits
    }

    public final void provisionsTable() {
        displayProvisionsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        displayProvisionsPanel.add(displayContent4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        displayProvisionsPanel.add(displayButton4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        displayProvisionsPanel.add(displayTable4, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        displayContent4.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
        displayContent4.add(itemName);
        displayContent4.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
        displayContent4.add(itemPrice);
        displayContent4.add(new JLabel("Item Company"));
        displayContent4.add(itemCompany);
        displayContent4.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
        displayContent4.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
        displayContent4.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
        displayContent4.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
        displayContent4.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
        displayContent4.add(quantityInStock);

        displayButton4.add(addNew);
        displayButton4.add(save);
        displayButton4.add(view);
        displayButton4.add(exit);

        view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                Connection con = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                }

                Statement state = null;
                ResultSet set = null;

                try {

                    String Query = "SELECT * FROM Provisions";
                    state = con.createStatement();
                    set = state.executeQuery(Query);

                    boolean nextrec = set.next();
                    if (!nextrec) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Record");
                    } else {
                        Vector col = new Vector();
                        Vector row = new Vector();

                        ResultSetMetaData rsm = set.getMetaData();

                        for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                            col.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(x));
                        }
                        do {
                            row.addElement(getNextRow(set, rsm));
                        } while (set.next());

                        JTable tab = new JTable(row, col);
                        displayContent.removeAll();
                        displayTable.removeAll();
                        displayTable.add(new JScrollPane(tab), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                        validate();
                    }
                    state.close();
                } catch (SQLException sql) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, sql.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    String Query = "INSERT INTO Provisions VALUES ('" + itemName.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + itemPrice.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + itemCompany.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityOfitemsBought.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityOfitemsSold.getText() + "',"
                            + "          '" + quantityInStock.getText() + "')";

                    String db_url = "jdbc:odbc:ProjectSalesDatabase";
                    String username = "";
                    String password = "";
                    Connection con = null;
                    try {
                        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException f) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, f.getMessage());
                    }
                    Statement state = con.createStatement();
                    int rep = state.executeUpdate(Query);
                    if (rep == 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No Data Saved");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Saved");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    sqle.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });

        addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {

                    itemName.setText("");
                    itemPrice.setText("");
                    itemCompany.setText("");
                    quantityOfitemsBought.setText("");
                    quantityOfitemsSold.setText("");
                    quantityInStock.setText("");

                    displayTable.removeAll();
                    displayContent.removeAll();

                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Name"));
                    displayContent.add(itemName);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Price"));
                    displayContent.add(itemPrice);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Item Company"));
                    displayContent.add(itemCompany);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Bought"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsBought);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity Of Items Sold"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityOfitemsSold);
                    displayContent.add(new JLabel("Quantity In Stock"));
                    displayContent.add(quantityInStock);

                    validate();

                } catch (Exception f) {
                    f.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Vector getNextRow(ResultSet set, ResultSetMetaData rsm) {
        Vector currentRow = new Vector();
        try {
            for (int x = 1; x <= rsm.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                switch (rsm.getColumnType(x)) {
                    case Types.VARCHAR:
                        currentRow.addElement(set.getString(x));
                        break;
                    case Types.INTEGER:
                        currentRow.addElement(new Long(set.getLong(x)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("No column type known");
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.getMessage();
        }
        return currentRow;
    }
    }
```

Comment: yeah works fine thanks but one more question though not related to the topic - how do I make a particular JFrame (the application has several JFrames popping up pending user action(s)) close without closing the entire application. The JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE closes all open JFrames of the application.

Comment: please accept the answer. If this solved your problem. Under the big zero, there is right mark, click on it...